# QtQuick.LocalStorage dont work properly with qmlscene from Qt Designer Studio

Tags: qt, qml, local-storage, qtquick2, qt-designer

When I run Qmlscene preview from Qt Designer Studio trial , for standart example project (Clock ) which using QtQuick.LocalStorage it dont work. Log showing **Error: LocalStorage: can't create path C:\Users\leo\AppData\Local\QtProject\QtQmlViewer\QML\OfflineStorage\Databases**
from LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync(...) function.

Explored Qt sources i found [source of localstorage plugin](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/imports/localstorage/plugin.cpp?h=dev)  where was this part

```
QString basename = args->v4engine()->qmlEngine()->offlineStorageDatabaseFilePath(dbname);
QFileInfo dbFile(basename);
if (!QDir().mkpath(dbFile.dir().absolutePath())) {
const QString message = QQmlEngine::tr("LocalStorage: can't create path %1").arg(QDir::toNativeSeparators(dbFile.dir().absolutePath()));
V4THROW_SQL2(SQLEXCEPTION_DATABASE_ERR, message);
}
QString dbid = dbFile.fileName();
bool created = false;
QString version = dbversion;
QSqlDatabase database;
```

So I think there is some problem to open/create database file on default path for qt projects by qmlscene. I cant change default path and cant set offlineStorage(path) becouse i have not access to C++ code (its .qmlproject).
When I run project (not using menu item "QML Preview") or build it with C++ qmlengine loader its working normal with localstorage, but when i try to preview via QML scene tool from Qt Design Studio it show error.

Have somebody ideas how fix it or other way to use localstorage in QMLscene tool ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is bug and not decided. I found new way to store local data by write wrapers for Qt.lab.settings instantiated in Singleton qml file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just creating a bugreport?